# How to input list of users into batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am looking to input a list of users kept in users.txt into a batch file to reset permissions. When i put a * it will go down the list of folders and reset permissions correctly but I am wanting to limit the scope of the permission setting. Each user in the list corresponds with a name of a folder that i want to re-permission.

This script works but works on every folder and i cant limit the scope.

```
cd C:\Users\matt\desktop\subinacl

for /D %%i in (*) do (

subinacl /file %%i /perm /grant=%%i=C "/grant=\domain admins=f"  "/grant=system=f"         "/grant=creator owner=f" /setowner=%%i 
subinacl /subdirectories %%i\* /perm /grant=%%i=f "/grant=domain admins=f"   "/grant=SYSTEM=f" "/grant=creator owner=f" /setowner=%%i )
```

This is what I am trying to do but use a list of folder names to re-permission those folders and its not working. It inputs users.txt into the grant= location instead of the actual list.

```
cd C:\Users\matt\desktop\subinacl
SET users=users.txt

for /D %%i in (%users%) do (

subinacl /file %%i /perm /grant=%%i=C "/grant=domain admins=f"  "/grant=system=f"  "/grant=creator owner=f" /setowner=%%i 
subinacl /subdirectories %%i\* /perm /grant=%%i=f "/grant=domain admins=f" "/grant=SYSTEM=f" "/grant=creator owner=f" /setowner=%%i )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am looking to call from a list of users into a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
cd C:\Users\matt\desktop\subinacl
SET users=users.txt

for /f "delims=" %%i in (%users%) do (
 for /D %%i in (*) do (

 echo subinacl /file %%i /perm /grant=%%i=C "/grant=domain admins=f"  "/grant=system=f"  "/grant=creator owner=f" /setowner=%%i 
 echo subinacl /subdirectories %%i\* /perm /grant=%%i=f "/grant=domain admins=f" "/grant=SYSTEM=f" "/grant=creator owner=f" /setowner=%%i
)
```

)

I've not used `subinacl` so I've just echoed the proposed commands.

Personally, I'd suggest using your very original version to set the admin, etc perms, then use the `users.txt` file to set the individual permissions. As I've listed it, the admin, etc. perms would be applied again for each entry in `users.txt`